# Symfony 4.4 Querybuilder exclude all events during a weekend

Tags: symfony4, query-builder, weekend

Got a question, I have a query where I have to exclude events based on their days.

I have to eliminate all events where the dateStart occurs during a weekend (Friday from 19:30:00 till Sunday). But for some reason this one returned an event that was on a Sunday...

Does anyone have a clue what's wrong with the query and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php 
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->select('count(r.id)')
    ->leftJoin('r.events', 're')
    ->leftJoin('r.user', 'ru');
    ->andWhere("DAYOFWEEK(re.dateStart) NOT IN (:weekend)")->setParameter('weekend', [1,7]); // Sat and Sunday
    ->andWhere("DAYOFWEEK(re.dateStart) != :day AND (DATE_FORMAT(re.dateStart, '%T')) = :hour")
    ->setParameter('hour', '19:30:00'])
    ->setParameter('day', 6); // Friday
```